# ReactJS cannot use composed components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my super simple enhancer:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

function BaseComponent(ComposedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        static displayName = "BaseComponent";

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        updateState(obj) {
            if (this.isMounted() && obj) {
                this.setState(obj);
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (

                <ComposedComponent {...this.props} {...this.states} />
            )
        }
    }
}

export default BaseComponent;
```

And I'm enhancing my component as follows:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import BaseComponent from '../composits/Base.jsx';

@BaseComponent
class Home extends React.Component {
    static displayeName = 'Home';

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.updateState)

        return (
            <div>Hi</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

But this does not work! `console.log(this.updateState)` is `null`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Maybe I'm missing something here. By the design I have above, will `Home` be the "enhanced" component, or `BaseComponent`? On otherwords, would `Home` have access to `BaseComponent` methods/states/props or the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a name

```
function baseComponent(ComposedComponent) {
    return class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
        // ommited
    }
}

 export default baseComponent;
```

Or try to wrap it

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import BaseComponent from '../composits/Base.jsx';

class Home extends React.Component {
    // ommited
}

export default BaseComponent(Home);
```

Comment: I'm using ES7 decorators to "wrap" my function. And naming the base class did not help

Comment: Yes i have. I tried both explicit calling, and the decorator, but none of them work.

Comment: Can you try to 'console.log' something in constructor of 'BaseComponent' to be sure it's even called

Comment: Yeah it is. The constructor for sure is called